# Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'WidthC' was corrupted

Tags: c++, windows, user-interface, winapi

This Code Throw `Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'WidthC' was corrupted.` This Code Draws Button.

After Adding This.
`INT WidthC; GetCharWidth(ControlStyles->hDC, 0, length, &WidthC);`

But If I Ignore Error Program works and `GetCharWidth()` function returns character Width, but after program exit from DrawItem Function Error Occurs. Error Occurs after destroying WidthC variable.

---

```cpp
    if (ControlStyles->CtlID == ID_PREVIEW_BUTTON || ControlStyles->CtlID == ID_PREVIEW_STATIC || ControlStyles->CtlID == ID_PREVIEW_EDIT) {
        SetTextColor(ControlStyles->hDC, PreviewTextControlColor);
        SetBkMode(ControlStyles->hDC, PreviewControlsBackgroundMode);
        if (PreviewControlsBackgroundMode == OPAQUE) {
            SetBkColor(ControlStyles->hDC, PreviewTextBackgroundControlColor);
        }
        FillRect(ControlStyles->hDC, &ControlStyles->rcItem, CreateSolidBrush(PreviewBackgroundControlColor));
        WCHAR StaticText[MAX_NAME_STRING] = { 0 };
        INT length = GetWindowText(ControlStyles->hwndItem, StaticText, ARRAYSIZE(StaticText));
        INT WidthC;
        GetCharWidth(ControlStyles->hDC, 0, length, &WidthC);
        TextOut(ControlStyles->hDC, ControlStyles->rcItem.right / 2 - ((length - 1) * WidthC) / 2, ControlStyles->rcItem.bottom / 2 - FontSize / 2, StaticText, length);
    }
```

Comment: `WidthC` not a buffer of length INT elements. [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharwidthw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharwidthw)

Comment: ***But If I Ignore Error Program works.*** Unfortunately sometimes broken code appears to work. That is the worst behavior of undefined behavior. Thankfully your debugger told you that you were corrupting the stack.

Comment: Have you got any updates? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answers. If not, just feel free to contact us. Your understanding and cooperation will be grateful.

Comment: Is Better Function For `GetCharWidth()` and Is `GetTextExtentPoint()`

Answer (score 1):

The 4th parameter of `GetCharWidth()` expects a pointer to a buffer that can hold as many `INT`s as are in the range of characters you specify in the 2nd and 3rd parameters.  Since you are asking for a range of `length` number of characters, you need a buffer of `length` number of `INT`s.  But, you are passing in the address of a single `INT`, so you will overwrite surrounding memory if `length > 1` is true.

So, you would need something more like this instead:

```
WCHAR StaticText[MAX_NAME_STRING] = { 0 };
INT length = GetWindowText(ControlStyles->hwndItem, StaticText, ARRAYSIZE(StaticText));
if (length) {
    INT WidthC[MAX_NAME_STRING] = { 0 };
    GetCharWidth(ControlStyles->hDC, 0, length-1, WidthC);
    // use WidthC[0]..WidthC[length-1] as needed...
}
```

Or, perhaps you meant to do this instead for a single `INT`:

```
WCHAR StaticText[MAX_NAME_STRING] = { 0 };
INT length = GetWindowText(ControlStyles->hwndItem, StaticText, ARRAYSIZE(StaticText));
if (length) {
    INT WidthC;
    GetCharWidth(ControlStyles->hDC, 0, 0, WidthC);
    // use WidthC as needed...
}
```

That being said, `GetCharWidth()` is long deprecated, you should be using `GetCharWidth32()` instead, as the documentation says:

> **Note** This function is provided only for compatibility with 16-bit versions of Windows. Applications should call the [`GetCharWidth32`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getcharwidth32w) function, which provides more accurate results.

Comment: I Found More Useful Function ```GetTextExtentPoint()```.